Flask program runs inconsistently and doesn't redirect pages correctly
I cant understand what's going wrong I leave the program working the next time it's not it just gives me an internal server error I try fixing things my self I try using chatgpt from the first look it says that my code should work properly and then when I say the problem it just start yapping about do this do that and nothing really worked now I opened the application it was working but when I try navigating thru the url it says url not found but now its not working no more it just gives me internal server error
python create.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import sqlite3
import hashlib


app = Flask(__name__)


def init_db():
    with sqlite3.connect("user_login_data.db") as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                username TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
                password TEXT NOT NULL
            )
        """)
        connection.commit()


init_db()

@app.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        confirm_password = request.form.get("confirm_password")

        if password != confirm_password:
            error = "Passwords do not match."
            
        else:
            hashed_password = hashlib.sha1(password.encode()).hexdigest()
            try:
                with sqlite3.connect("user_login_data.db") as connection:
                    cursor = connection.cursor()
                    cursor.execute(
                        "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)",
                        (username, hashed_password)
                    )
                    connection.commit()
                    return redirect(url_for('home'))
            except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
                error = "Username already exists. Please try another."

    return render_template("signup.html")


@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")



python app.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import hashlib
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")

        hashed_password = hashlib.sha1(password.encode()).hexdigest()

        connection = sqlite3.connect('user_login_data.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        query = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?"
        cursor.execute(query, (username, hashed_password))
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        if len(result) == 0:
            error = "Username or password is incorrect."
            return render_template("index.html")

        else:
            return render_template("home_page.html")

    
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/signup')
def signup():
    return render_template("signup.html")



signup.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <div class="main">
        <h1 class = "sign" >Create an Account</h1>
        <form method="POST" class = "form">
            <br><br>
            <label for="username"></label>
            <input class = "un" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username here " required>
            <br>
            <label for="username"></label>
            <input class = "pass" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password here" required>
            <br>
            <label for="username"></label>
            <input class = "pass" type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Re-enter password here" required>
            <br><br><br>
            <button class = "submit" type="submit">Create Account</button>
            <br><br><br>
            <p class="forgot" align="center"> have an account? ? <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"> Sign in</a> </p>

        </form>
    </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        
    <div class = "main"> 
        <h1 class = "sign"> Sign in </h1>
        <form method="POST" class = "form1" >
            <br>
            <input class = "un" type="text" name="username"  align="center" placeholder="Username" required>
            <input class= "pass" type="password" name="password" align="center" placeholder="Password" minlength="8" required />
            <input class = "submit" type="submit"  value="Sign in" />
            <br><br>
            
            <p class="forgot" align="center"> Don't have an account? ? <a href="{{ url_for('signup')}}"> Sign up</a> </p>
            
        </form>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>

when I first downloaded python it wasn't getting recognized by vs code I've tried different versions but nothing worked then I found the solution which is was by changing the path. finally python was getting recognized but flask wasn't it kept saying import "flask" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)[Ln 1,col 6] but when ever I write flask run in terminal the development server show up but then Ive found the solution by pressing CRTL+SHFT+P then writing python:select interpreter then selecting python 3.12.7 this fixed flask being not recognized.
when ever I run the code now it just gives an output of this :
PS C:\Users\nsbou\OneDrive\Desktop\web project> flask run 
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
[2024-11-22 19:45:49,515] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1511, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 919, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 917, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 902, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\OneDrive\Desktop\web project\app.py", line 32, in login
    return render_template("index.html")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 150, in render_template
    return _render(app, template, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 131, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1304, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 939, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\OneDrive\Desktop\web project\templates\index.html", line 25, in top-level template code
    <p class="forgot" align="center"> Don't have an account?<a href="{{ url_for('sign_up') }}"> Sign up</a>
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1121, in url_for
    return self.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1110, in url_for
    rv = url_adapter.build(  # type: ignore[union-attr]
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nsbou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing\map.py", line 924, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'sign_up'. Did you mean 'signup' instead?
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2024 19:45:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -


The endpoint name, and function name, are great.
@app.route('/sign-up', ... )
def sign_up():

The diagnostic suggests that your web browser navigated
to /sign_up, when /sign-up was intended.
Somewhat confusingly, you also have a perfectly nice /signup endpoint
which serves static content. Consider making its name slightly longer,
to avoid potential confusion.

Thx I really appreciate your help, and I will definitely take your suggestions and implement them right away. That said, I’ve encountered a major issue that I’m struggling to understand. I left my development server running in browser and   displaying an "Internal Server Error" on the tab. However, after several hours, the page loaded with the styles applied. Of course, it didn’t function properly because the code wasn’t running, but I’m just trying to figure out why this keeps happening. Do I need to uninstall and reinstall VS Code to fix this issue, or is something else causing the problem?
